# ReferenceError: URL is not defined in Azure javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, azure-functions

I'm using Azure Function App to handle simple API calls. I'm using JavaScript as the language. I developed locally and tested with `func host start` and confirmed everything working as needed. Part of the code is parsing a URL.  I have the following in my function code:

```
const url = require('url');
let myUrl = new URL(someInputParameter);
```

As indicated, this works fine when tested locally, however when deployed in azure, I receive this error message:

```
018-12-11T10:40:56.236 [Error] Executed 'Functions.myFunction' (Failed, Id=d7d51ed1-d37e-44ec-91d0-070de2005c1c)
Result: Failure
Exception: ReferenceError: URL is not defined
Stack: ReferenceError: URL is not defined
    at module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\myFunction\index.js:8:15)
    at WorkerChannel.invocationRequest (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12210\32bit\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:28862:26)
    at ClientDuplexStream.WorkerChannel.eventStream.on (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12210\32bit\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:28752:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at Object.onReceiveMessage (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12210\32bit\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:42351:19)
    at InterceptingListener.module.exports.InterceptingListener.recvMessageWithContext (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12210\32bit\workers\node\worker-bundle.js:41678:19)
```

Do note that I do `require('url')`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: javascript is case sensitive

Comment: @ztadic91 URL is part of the global object, the OP shouldn't actually need to load `url = require("url");` at all in order to have it. However my assumption is that Azure doesn't have it available in their runtime.

Comment: @drinchev javascript is run on azure functions not the browser, i am not sure if the windows object is available? Please share a link to the docs if you thinks so, ty

Comment: [Browser-compatible URL class, implemented by following the WHATWG URL Standard. Examples of parsed URLs may be found in the Standard itself. The URL class is also available on the global object.](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api)

Comment: JavaScript function in Azure is run on Node.js. Also, everything works fine in local environment using MS provided tools.

Comment: @drinchev Note that there is no browser in this case - it's a Node.js application running in Azure.

Comment: Yep I'm pretty aware of that. That's why I linked the NodeJS docs. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. The code runs in Node 8, therefore `require` line needs to look like this:

```
const { URL } = require('url');
```

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: @JerryLiu Please do not make significant changes to existing accepted answer.  If it's a comment, post a comment. If it's something significantly different, post it as your own answer

Comment: Sorry for my reckless, I thought it was just a complement as you have found the key point that causes the trouble, will add a comment instead.

Comment: If we set `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`(In Application settings) to 10.14.1(latest in Azure), we don't have to import url module. Simply use `let myUrl = new URL(someInputParameter);`

Answer (score 0):

I updated to latest stable version of node (nvm use 16 in my case).

This alone did not work, at least in my case.  I could see that my script kept running under node v8.

On mac, use Go To Folder in finder (in my case): /Users/{me}/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0

Delete bin.

Ran my script again without any extra require statements and works as expected.

Comment: What does Mac have to do with Azure function? As I wrote, everything worked perfectly fine on local.

Comment: Good question.  Replies are not only meant for the original poster, right?  In case someone else is reading this thread... which I think is safe to assume... they might just need to take the same extra step that I did - on my mac (which is obviously local as well)